# ipad storyboard in xcode cannot drag button

Tags: xcode, drag-and-drop, storyboard

I'm running xcode 4.5.2 to write an iOS app for both iphone & ipad ("universal" app).

I'm able to use the iphone storyboard to drag & drop buttons, labels, etc onto it. In fact I have functioning code on the iphone side.

However, since the beginning, I have not been able to drag & drop anything onto the ipad storyboard. When I try to do so the buttons, labels, etc just "bounce off".

Is there a way to reset the iPad storyboard so that I can get a clean start? It potentially could be that I had mistakenly (this is my very first iOS app) dragged a view or view controller onto the ipad story board. I tried deleting it but the whole ipad storyboard disappears after that.

It is probably something very simple but I'm very new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can only drag & drop items into a view if you are in the most "zoomed-in" way of viewing it.  Try pressing the "=" in the bottom right corner when you bring up your iPad storyboard (this will toggle between the most zoomed-in and the most previous zoom out).  Once it zooms you in all the way, try dropping something onto your view again.

EDIT: Per Xcode 8 Release Notes, Interface Builder should now allow editing at all zoom levels.

Comment: beauty! that's it! zooming in did the trick. Thanks a lot, GeneralMike!

Comment: No problem.  I really think they should make that more clear.  I didn't know it when I first started, and I just happened to read it in another post on this site when I was looking up something completely unrelated.

Comment: I would've never guessed that! They should fix it or have some message indicating that it is the zoomed out status thats causing the  objects to bounce off.